# Google Earth Engine formaTrend function

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, function

So I'm using the formaTrend() function in Google Earth Engine to detect differences in forest cover over time (via long-trend). My question is if there's a paper or an explanation to what exactly formaTrend() does. 
I've read the description of the function in GEE itself but its very brief and I was wondering if there's a longer/more detailed description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions come from the short and long term trends as specified in this paper:

Hammer, Dan and Kraft, Robin and Wheeler, David, Forma: Forest Monitoring for Action - Rapid Identification of Pan-Tropical Deforestation Using Moderate-Resolution Remotely Sensed Data (November 17, 2009). Center for Global Development Working Paper No. 192. DOI: 10.2139/ssrn.1517934

Available at: https://www.cgdev.org/sites/default/files/1423248_file_Hammer_Kraft_Wheeler_FORMA_FINAL.pdf

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, thanks a lot!